Size of iterated sumsets in $\mathbb{F}_2^n$
Given $A \subseteq \mathbb{F}_2^n$, let $kA = \{a_1 + ... + a_k : a_1, ..., a_k \in A\}$. Clearly $|kA| \leq |A|^k$. There are sets of size $n$ for which $nA = \mathbb{F}_2^n$, namely any basis. Letting $e_1,..., e_n$ denote the standard basis and setting $A = \{e_1, ..., e_n, e_1 + ... + e_n\}$, we can see that $(n-1)A = \mathbb{F}_2^n$. In fact, I think $(n/2)A = \mathbb{F}_2^n$: if $x \in \mathbb{F}_2^n$ has Hamming weight at least $n/2$, we can write as a smaller sum by using the all $1$'s vector $e_1 + ... + e_n$.
These simple examples show that there's some type of trade-off here between $|A|$ and the minimum $k$ for which $kA = \mathbb{F}_2^n$. When $A$ is a basis, we need long sums to express every element in $\mathbb{F}_2^n$, and as we add more redundancy to $A$ we can express all of $\mathbb{F}_2^n$ using shorter and shorter sums.
Do sets $A$ with size at most polynomial in $n$ need $k = \Omega(n)$ in order to satisfy $kA = \mathbb{F}_2^n$? Does every constant-density set $A$ admit a constant $k$?
(I know there is plenty of work on sumsets: e.g. considering dense sets $A$ whose sumsets contain a large subspace, or something like that. I was hoping someone more familiar with this area might have something to share.)
